# Not able to debug in TypeScript - VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript, vscode-debugger

I am unable to open the localhost and unable to debug TypeScript file in VS Code because of some error. I have set **target** to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "--remote-debugging-port=9222"` in **Chrome Properties**. I got the error as `[debugger-for-chrome] Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222`. Refer the following image for error after killing all `chrome.exe` processes. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

[image: Failed to Load Error]

**.vscode/launch.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

**app/app.ts:**

```
var x = 1;
console.log(x); //made debugger here in VS Code
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>TypeScript Debugger</h3>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try killing all `chrome.exe` processes in your Task Manager and then try launching again with the remote debugging flag

Comment: Can you post those text files as, you know, text? If someone wanted to recreate your situation, they'd have to retype all of that code.

Comment: @Gideon I have tried killing all chrome.exe processes. Now I got `"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:3000/)"` error which you can refer in this post which i just edited

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have edited this post. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Much better, but please do include the text of the error message. The problem is that images are not searchable, so people trying to find this by searching would be out of luck.

Comment: @AbrahamGnanasingh According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/55), launching VS Code with Administrator privileges fixed it for someone, so you could try that?

Comment: @Gideon I restarted my system and opened VS Code by running as Admin. Still I got the same error. I am opening in `Launch localhost with sourcemaps`. Did I configured everything correctly in `launch.json` file and `target` in Chrome Properties?

Comment: @Gideon can you check my other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131709/tns-run-android-emulator-not-working-nativescript) regarding nativescript emulator issue and give me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly answering the question but perhaps still useful: did you know that you can debug typescript directly in Chrome, including breakpoints? You don't even need to install a plugin. 
See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: this is cool. but how can i debug `nativescript js` project(for android & ios) in vs code?

Comment: can you check my other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131709/tns-run-android-emulator-not-working-nativescript) regarding nativescript emulator issue and give me a solution?