# tns run android --emulator not working - NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

I have followed the steps in this [link](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1). When I run using the command `tns run android --emulator`, I got the following error in command prompt

```
Configuring > 0/4 projects > root projectError: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:552:26)
```

Following is the error screenshot for your reference.

[image: tns emulator error]

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this has been caused by old modules. In regard to that you could follow the steps here - https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions to update NativeScript. In addition delete `/platform` and `/node_modules` folders from the project. If you expire the same project you could try to use Genymotion - https://www.genymotion.com/, it is free for personal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by updating `tns-core-modules` using the command `npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save`. After that, I have enabled the `Virtualization Technology` in BIOS on system startup. Now the emulator is working fine.